# Given $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $[0,\infty)$ and $F(x)= \int_0^x x f(t)dt$. Find $F^\prime$.

Tags: calculus

I've attempted to solve the problem, but I found $F^\prime$ dependent on $F(x)$. Can it be that simple? xD

If $G(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$, then
$F(x)=x*G(x)$.
Therefore $F'(x)=xG'(x)+G(x) \Rightarrow
F'(x)=x*f(x)+F(x)/x$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Equation formatting could use work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $G(x,y)=\int_0^xyf(t)dt$, $F(x)=G(x,x)$. $dG=yf(x)dx+\int_0^xf(t)dt dy$ and $F'(x)=xf(x)+\int_0^xf(t)dt$

Comment: Thank you kind sir!